# Manipulating a list<array[]>, is this thread safe?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

If i had a list containing 4 long[], is it possible to assign a thread to each long[] and modify it? No thread is technically trying to modify data another thread should be accessing.

```
long[] array1 = new long[4]{1,2,3,4};
long[] array2 = new long[4]{2,4,5,6};
long[] array3 = new long[4]{3,4,8,9};
long[] array4 = new long[4]{4,5,8,10};

List<long[]> myList = new List<long[]>();

myList.Add(array1);
myList.Add(array2);
myList.Add(array3);
myList.Add(array4);
```

Then using task factory, get thread 1 to multiply each element in array1 by 1. Thread 2 multiplies each element in thread 2 by 2, etc. So the final config would be

```
1,2,3,4
4,8,10,12
9,12,24,27
16,20,32,40
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays can be accessed by multiple threads, provided you're not trying to access the *same element of the array* from two threads.

`List<T>`, internally, just wraps an array, so reading elements from the `List<T>` will also be fine.  (Note: Adding to the list is not thread safe, as this can require a resize of the internal array.)

This means that your code should work fine, as you're merely reading from the `List<T>`, and writing to arrays.

Your code could be easily written as:

```
Parallel.For(0, myList.Count, i =>
{
    long[] values = myList[i];
    for (int j=0;j<values.Length;++j)
       values[j] *= i + 1;
});
```

Note that, since your first "loop" iteration just multiplies the values `* 1`, it can be skipped by starting at 1:

```
Parallel.For(1, myList.Count, i =>
{
    long[] values = myList[i];
    for (int j=0;j<values.Length;++j)
       values[j] *= i + 1;
});
```

Comment: They could also use a `Parallel.Foreach(...)`

Comment: @Douglas No, it should be `(0` - it's *from inclusive*.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783539.aspx

Comment: @Tyler ForEach would be much more difficult in this situation, since the OP needs the index to perform the math operation.  `For` is more appropriate because of the required logic.

Comment: @ReedCopsey ah yes I missed that part my bad.

Comment: @ReedCopsey: What I mean is: `values[j] *= (i + 1);`. The OP wants the first array to be multiplied by `1`, not `0`.

Comment: Yup. And as a matter of preference, I would agree with @Tyler's point, although it requires the use of the [`ForEach` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783359.aspx) that provides the loop index.

Answer (score 0):

*The structures* you're using are not inherently thread-safe, but *the process* that you've defined would be safe to do with these structures as you're working around the limitations by having only one thread per array.

Comment: There is no such thing as “inherently thread-safe structure”, thread safety is a property of a specific program (or part of it), not of a structure. For example, you can use `ConcurrentDictionary` in a way that is not thread-safe and you can also use a simple array in a way that is thread-safe.

Comment: Perhaps we have different definitions of a structure or inherently thread-safe. From my point of view, a structure is just an object which has methods and data. Said object can be designed in such a way that it is thread-safe to use its methods that operate on its data (they are, after all, just a small part of a program). I'd consider that object to be inherently thread-safe, because you're safe to use it based on its design (outside of read/assignment of its own instance, obviously).

Comment: My point is, even if every single operation of the structure is thread-safe, it doesn't magically make any code that uses it thread safe. Consider code like this: `if (dict.ContainsKey(key)) dict[key] = 1; else dict[key]++;`. This code is not thread safe and it doesn't matter if `dict` is a normal `Dictionary` or if it's `ConcurrentDictionary` (which, I assume, is supposed to be “inherently thread safe” according to you).

Comment: Yeah, so clearly we're talking about thread safety differently. I think most people would consider `Interlocked.Increment` to be a thread-safe function by design. But you can use it in a way that is not thread-safe. That's true for anything. Yet I consider that function to be inherently thread-safe. And I would consider an object/structure that includes just those types of functions to be inherently thread-safe. `List<>` however is _not_ designed to be thread-safe in any way. There's a striking difference between the two and "inherent thread-safety" is how I chose to express that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Blocking Collection which is thread safe.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx

Comment: Using `BlockingCollection` wouldn't help here in any way.